# Split dataframe into 5 parts and use describe function for every part

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply, purrr

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = runif(100))
```

And I splitted it into 5 parts:

```
z <- split(df, rep(1:5, length.out = nrow(df), each = ceiling(nrow(df)/5)))
```

Now I'm trying to find descriptive statistics for every part in `z` but I'm getting this error: (I'm actually interested in finding descriptive statistics of `df$y` column in these 5 parts.)

```
psych::describe(z,na.rm = TRUE)

Error in var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) : 
  is.atomic(x) is not TRUE
Ek olarak: Warning message:
In mean.default(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I'm trying to find something like this: (probably it won't look like `z[1]$y`, but assume that that's what I'm trying to find please)

```
           vars     n   mean     sd median trimmed    mad   min    max  range skew kurtosis   se
z[1]$y       5 44813   0.02   0.17   0.00    0.01   0.10 -0.97   8.87   9.84 6.19   211.87 0.00
....
z[5]$y       6 45220   0.15   0.07   0.14    0.15   0.05  0.05   0.81   0.76 3.83    31.53 0.00
```

Also, how can I use describe function for only `y` values in `z[1]` or `z[5]`?

I'm not sure about how to handle the list here, so thanks and appreciating your response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use the following solution. I am not familiar with `describe` function you are using, but if it takes a vector as its first argument you can use `imap` function of package `purrr` to specify you only want to apply your function on `1`st & `5`th elements. `.y` argument in `imap` refers to positions/names as `.x` refers to values:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

imap(z, ~ if(.y %in% c(1, 5)) {
  describe(.x[["y"]])
} else {
  .x
})
```

Here is another more compact solution in base R, suggested by my dear friend @akrun:

```
z[c("1", "5")] <- lapply(z[c("1", "5")], describe)
```

Comment: That's my pleasure. If there is something I could explain more, just let me know.

Comment: Nice solution Anoushiravan R!

Comment: Thank you my dear friend, you are missed here :)

Comment: Isn't this `z[c("1", "5")] <- lapply(z[c("1", "5")], describe)`

Comment: @akrun yes exactly. I thought the OP wanted a tidyverse solution and it added to my personal preference :D

Comment: I will add it to my response with your permission :D . So in base R this is one way we replicate `imap`?

Comment: Sure.  With tidyverse, you may also use `map_if`

Comment: I thought `map_if` would only apply its predicate function on elements and not their names.

Comment: Or may also do this in a single step with `nest_by` `df %>% nest_by(grp = rep(1:5, length.out = n(), each = ceiling(nrow(df)/5))) %>% mutate(data = if(any(c(1, 5) %in% grp)) list(describe(data[[1]])) else list(data))`

Comment: This sounds cool too. But I have one question, I can't check list elements names like this one `1:5` with `map_if`, can I? It should be either `imap` or `map2` I suppose.

Answer (score 5):

We could use `lapply`

```
library(psych)

n <- 20
nr <- nrow(df)
z <- split(df, rep(1:ceiling(nr/n), each=n, length.out=nr))

lapply(z, psych::describe)
```

Output:

```
$`1`
  vars  n  mean   sd median trimmed  mad min   max range skew kurtosis   se
x    1 20 10.50 5.92   10.5   10.50 7.41   1 20.00 19.00 0.00    -1.38 1.32
y    2 20  0.37 0.30    0.3    0.34 0.32   0  0.96  0.96 0.47    -1.13 0.07

$`2`
  vars  n  mean   sd median trimmed  mad   min   max range skew kurtosis   se
x    1 20 30.50 5.92  30.50   30.50 7.41 21.00 40.00 19.00 0.00    -1.38 1.32
y    2 20  0.43 0.29   0.39    0.42 0.34  0.01  0.96  0.95 0.41    -1.14 0.06

$`3`
  vars  n  mean   sd median trimmed  mad   min   max range  skew kurtosis   se
x    1 20 50.50 5.92  50.50   50.50 7.41 41.00 60.00 19.00  0.00    -1.38 1.32
y    2 20  0.55 0.34   0.51    0.56 0.49  0.03  0.98  0.95 -0.08    -1.62 0.08

$`4`
  vars  n  mean   sd median trimmed  mad   min   max range skew kurtosis   se
x    1 20 70.50 5.92  70.50   70.50 7.41 61.00 80.00 19.00 0.00    -1.38 1.32
y    2 20  0.52 0.27   0.46    0.52 0.39  0.15  0.94  0.79 0.12    -1.59 0.06

$`5`
  vars  n  mean   sd median trimmed  mad   min    max range  skew kurtosis   se
x    1 20 90.50 5.92  90.50   90.50 7.41 81.00 100.00 19.00  0.00    -1.38 1.32
y    2 20  0.62 0.33   0.65    0.65 0.43  0.01   0.99  0.98 -0.33    -1.48 0.07
```

Comment: When in doubt always use base R :)

Comment: This one works pretty well, too. Thank you so much!